# Getting an error when trying to make a response for API using Thymeleaf

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

```
<!DOCTYPE html  SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Title</title>
  <style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
       background-image: url(/images/3.png);
        height: 100vh;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden
}

.loginBox {
    margin-top: 10px
}
#particles-js {
    height: 100%
}

.loginBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 350px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.user2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px
}

h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    color: #59238F;
    text-align: center
}

.loginBox input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px
}

.loginBox input[type="text"],
.loginBox input[type="password"] {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #262626;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.loginBox input[type="text"]:hover,
.loginBox input[type="password"]:hover {
    color: #42F3FA;
    border: 1px solid #42F3FA;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 0, .3), 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 0, .2), 0 0 15px rgba(0, 255, 0, .1), 0 2px 0 black
}

.loginBox input[type="text"]:focus,
.loginBox input[type="password"]:focus {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #42F3FA
}

.inputBox {
    position: relative
}

.inputBox span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    color: #262626
}

.loginBox input[type="submit"] {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #59238F;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer
}

.loginBox a {
    color: #262626;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block
}

a:hover {
    color: #00ffff
}

p {
    color: #0000ff
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
<div class="loginBox"> <img class="user2" src="https://i.ibb.co/yVGxFPR/2.png" height="100px" width="100px">
  <h3>Sign Up Here</h3>
  <form th:action="@{/get_ragister}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
   
    <div class="inputBox">
       <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" th:field = "${name}"/>
   <p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="${name}"></p>
  </div>
    
    <div class="inputBox"> 
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" th:field = "${email}"/>
    <p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="${email}"></p>
    </div>
   
    <div class="inputBox"> 
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" th:field= "${password}"/>
   <p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="${password}"></p>
   </div>
    
    <div class="inputBox"> 
    <input type="password"  class="form-control" name="re_password" placeholder="Re_Password" th:field = "${re_password}"/>
    <p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('re_password')}" th:errors="${re_password}"></p>
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" name="Signup" value="Sign-up">
    <div id="register-link" class="text-right">
      <a href="/login.html">Sign In</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
Whitelabel Error Page  
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Oct 12 16:23:33 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 130, col 80)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 130, col 80)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:79)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:241)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:327)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseStandaloneElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:96)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:706)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    ... 63 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Does model has object of 'user' in it? It looks like thymeleaf is not able to find 'user' binding as specified here in the stacktrace.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute at
```